# Problems while installing Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am Unable to install Google chrome . I keep getting the same message . 
I am new to Ubuntu please help.

I have tried it by downloading deb file again and again but 
I keep getting same message.

Screen-shot of displayed message:

[image: Screenshot google-chrome-stable conflicts]

Comment: It's not an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed a 32-bit Chrome by mistake. Remove it by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable:i386
```

and install a 64-bit Chrome.